# Is the validation data set used for building the testing model?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization, hyperparameter

Let's assume I split my data into 70% training data, 20% validation data, and 10% testing data.
For each hyperparameter I am building a model using the training data and determine the best hyperparameter/model using the validation data.

Now, I want to determine the "final" performance.
For this purpose, do I build a final model with the best found hyperparameter using both, the training and validation data (90% of the data), and report the performance on the test data or do I re-use the best model from the validation phase (70% of the data) and simply report it's performance for the test data?

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to train on all the data (other than test) using the best found hyper-parameters. For example, in cross-validation, you don't have a single training/validation pair, so you'd naturally do the final training on all the training and validation data.

On the other hand, sometimes, (like in neural networks) you need a separate validation set to decide where to stop (i.e. epoch number). It's not common to choose the epoch number using validation set and retrain with all the data.